# fetch all data from firebase swift ios application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find the right query to pass to the firebase from ios application to bring in all data.

```
db.collection("users")
    .whereField("country", isEqualTo: country)
    .whereField("state", isEqualTo: state)
    .whereField("city", isEqualTo: city)
    .whereField("area", isEqualTo: area)
    .getDocuments
```

In the above code , lets say i am passing information from the ui. but i have an option in the dropdown to select "All" for Area. How do i pass that selection to firebase to bring in all the data regardless of area?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave off the where clause for area if you don't want to filter for area:

```
db.collection("users")
    .whereField("country", isEqualTo: country)
    .whereField("state", isEqualTo: state)
    .whereField("city", isEqualTo: city)
```

If you want to conditionally add it to the query, you will have to do something like this:

```
let query = db.collection("users")
    .whereField("country", isEqualTo: country)
    .whereField("state", isEqualTo: state)
    .whereField("city", isEqualTo: city)

if (area_should_be_used) {
    query = query.whereField("area", isEqualTo: area)
}

query.getDocuments()
```

You will have to determine the actual condition for `area_should_be_used`.

Comment: ok so technically firebase doesnt have anything like slect * from kind of solution type right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question.  If you're asking how to get all the documents in a collection, just don't add any where clauses to the query.